# CREATE PUBLICATION perfomance

Tags: postgresql, debezium

I want to create publications in several databases like this:

```
CREATE PUBLICATION dbz_publication FOR ALL TABLES;
```

My Debezium should not create them automatically, because the service that uses Debezium does not have superuser permissions, and it won't always use them.

**How does having a publication affect database performance?**

I tried to find information in the PostgreSQL documentation, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A publication that has no subscribers has no performance impact. It is just a definition sitting in the metadata for use with logical replication.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do I understand correctly that WAL streaming actually starts after the replication slot is created? For example: CREATE_REPLICATION_SLOT slot_name LOGICAL output_plugin;

Comment: No WAL is streamed with logical decoding (that's the whole point). It is the `START_REPLICATION` command that starts the flow of data, *after* a replication slot has been created.